# How to introduce an MSR in gem5 and integrate it with Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, gem5, msr

I am trying to evaluate performance of custom prefetching models for Intel x86 architecture for which I would like to set and read some MSR registers. We are using Gem5 and Linux 5.4.84 kernel on a TimingSimpleCPU.

I have introduced the registers at some unused address in these files:
https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/refs/heads/stable/src/arch/x86/regs/msr.cc
https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/refs/heads/stable/src/arch/x86/regs/misc.hh
say MY_CUSTOM_REGISTER at 0xc0010118

I have also defined these addresses in :
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/testing/selftests/kvm/include/x86_64/processor.h

as I felt that somehow we need to add definitions in the kernel too.

However, after building gem5.opt binary and kernel, I am not able to access these registers with msr-tools. I get a segmentation fault while trying to get/set any values:
sudo rdmsr 0xc0010118

Can someone point out somewhere else I need to add something?

Comment: Um, you can't add MSRs.  The MSRs that are available are determined by the processor.

Comment: Does the gem5 not determine the hardware and the processor from bottom up? Since we are trying to simulate the whole system, I guess we should be able to add MSRs?

Comment: My mistake.  I misunderstood the context.

Comment: I mean... you don't really need to modify the kernel source, the macros in `msr-index.h` and `kvm/.../processor.h` are just that, macros. If you are not using them anywhere in kernel code they are useless. If the CPU supports MSRs that the kernel does not know about (i.e. it does not have macro definitions or does not use them), you should *still* be able to access them through RDMSR/WRMSR. There's probably something wrong with your modifications to the Gem5 sources, you probably need to do something more.

Comment: I would try asking on the Gem5 mailing list or their Slack honestly.